# How to enable users to add content only from some pages (and only once) in  Drupal 7 

Tags: 7, nodes, users

i currently need to implement this use case in drupal.

We have two different type of users: registered users and moderators.

I need to do the following:

- registered users can add only one
  particular content type: videoCV (no
  help needed on this subject)
- registered users can add this content
  only from a pre-definite page called
  "Create you Video CV" (the page is
  accessible in the main menu) and only
  once
- moderators can add contents wherever
  they want.

so i need on these points:

1. how to limit to registered users the
   possibility to add content only on
   one page?I mean have the link add
   new content only on that page? (and
   also change that link so that it
   reads add your videoCV
2. how to limit users so that they can
   add just one content?

any help is appreciated, i think i can solve point number 1 withouth particular coding, but i think i need to create a custom module for point number 2, that is no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module usually bounds the users to create exactly one node of some content type that has been marked as Content Profile.

May this help you in this regard.

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry i didn't specify it sooner, but i'm using drupal 7